# ModelSim VHDL PLL test, 3 outputs, why does one start on a falling edge?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim, quartus

I setup a project to test the PLL (altpll) component of Quartus II suite.

There is a 50MHz external oscillator.  I setup the PLL to output 3 clocks: 100MHz, 400Mhz, and 10Mhz.

I imported everything into ModelSim to confirm it is running as expected.  Unexpectedly the 100MHz and 400MHz clock start on a rising edge, but the 10MHz clock starts on a falling edge.

Does anyone have any insight into why this is happening?

[image: clock edges]

I don't have the tools to confirm the actual FPGA behavior of the clock lines after PLL lock.

Comment: Does it really matter? They are clocks and their cycles will eventually align to have matching rising edges. Since it is an analog circuit, you have no way to know "where" you are in the cycles when the lock signal asserts, the only important thing is that the cycles are stable when it occurs.

Comment: You are probably right, I'm pretty new to this.  I guess if you needed a certain synchronization you'd manually wait for it and never expect your clocks to start synchronized?  The seemingly random behavior threw me. @JonathanDrolet

Comment: I guess you could, but it would be a bad design IMO. It should be sufficient to know the clocks' relationships and that they are synchronized by the PLL. Knowing where you are in the cycles should not be important, your design should work wherever you are when a statement is executed.